# how can I hide a ribbon item on project server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-project-server-2010

how can I hide a ribbon item (specifically Ribbon.ContextualTabs.ProjectCenter.Home.ChangeProjectType) on project server 2010?
I followed this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg549101(v=office.14).aspx) and it hides a ribbon item I want to, but it affects the functionality of the other ribbon items in the Tab; in a way that buttons don't be clicked and Comboboxes don't be filled. Here is my command:

```
<CustomAction
Id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.ProjectCenter.Home.ChangeProjectType"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
Title="Hides the ChangeProjectType button in the Project Center ribbon">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.ProjectCenter.Home.ChangeProjectType"/>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
```